# Condition on debroglie wavelength to probe the proton

Tags: wavefunction, protons

What is the condition of the debroglie wavelength of an e.g electron beam such that we can probe the proton?

Do we require that $\lambda < $size of proton or do we require that $\lambda ≈$ size of a quark?

Comment: Quarks have 0 size: they are point-like.  Much smaller than a fermi, the size of the proton, should work.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda must be as small as possible to map the interior of a proton, as was done at SLAC. A proton is a little less than 10^-15 meters in diameter. At 50 GeV, the SLAC electron beam had a wavelength of 2.5x10^-17 meters which was enough to reveal three *point-like* quarks inside the proton.